# How to read GPT drive in Mac?

Tags: macos, partition, filesystem

I've a 500GB external drive. First partition is 199.58GB (blue) and the second partition is 277.4GB (pink). I use this drive in my Windows 10 laptop before this and both partition are GPT type.

I already format first partition and it's now empty. The second partition contains lots of important data and I don't want to format it because I don't have backup of them.

When I connect the drive with my Mac (I'm running on OSX 10.11.4), I can see that the total drive size is 500GB like below:

[image]

But, only first partition appeared and I can't see the second partition (GPT) one.

[image]

What should I do now to read and access that GPT partition? Please help.

**UPDATE**

Running `diskutil list` command from terminal give me this. I believe that `Microsoft Reserved` is the partition that I'm looking for:

[image]

Comment: It's not whether it's GPT or MBR, it's that Mac can't read NTFS drives natively.

Comment: @Tetsujin but why I can still see the 199.58GB (blue) one? It's NTFS.

Comment: I don't know, because I don't know what you did. Your confusion over partition map type (MBR vs GPT[GUID]) & partition format type (NTFS vs OS X) means that your actions to reach that point are unclear.

Comment: sorry - I meant *write* to NTFS, my bad.

Comment: In situations like this, to help you unpick this problem, could you please tell us what you've already tried? When you say the first partition has been formatted, what did you do to format it? That Reserved partition should only be measured in MBs, not GBs, so something has happened to change that. And the Reserved partition shouldn't have any of your data in it. Have you used any repartitioning tools like GParted for example?

Answer (score 2):

The first step in situations like this is to use the mouse to select each visible part of the drive on the left and use the info button.

It will show you things that the command tool `diskutil` will if you open terminal and use it:

```
diskutil list
```

That will read the volume partition map and give you details on each partition with less detail than the info pane in disk utility. Once you know if the other partitions are NTFS or ext3 or another format, you can look for software or drivers to read that content. Worst case you have to pay for a commercial solution if you can't change the disk to a format that OS X reads (or writes if that is your requirement) natively.

Since Apple supports a wide variety of filesystems in read only mode, the most logical conclusion would be your drive isn't following standards or is damaged slightly and would mount properly once repaired or reformatted to standards. It's not uncommon for vendors to implement slight variations to filesystems that break compatibility on other OS.

- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemDetails/FileSystemDetails.html

Comment: thanks for the info. This is the result from the `diskutil list` command - http://i.imgur.com/uNxJQU0.png. I believe that `Microsoft Reserved` is the partition that I'm looking for. What should I do now?

Comment: @ZulhilmiZainudin That reserved description doesn't match what wikipedia has for the sizing. Perhaps windows is doing other things with that identifer of E3C9E316-0B5C-4DB8-817D-F92DF00215AE - if you run `sudo gpt show disk3` it should dump the identifications of each partition. It's likely you will need to connect to a PC and transfer the data, though. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Reserved_Partition

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you are experiencing is that OS X cannot natively read/write the NTFS partition.

My suggestion is to copy that data to another drive/partition, format the partition to something that OS X can read like ExFAT (if you want OS X and Windows compatibility), then copy your data back.

To read the NTFS partition so you can copy the files, you need to enable it.  Here are the steps

1. Make sure your NTFS drive has a single word name.  Using your example, rename it from "Untitled" to "UntitledNT" or something that can help you distinguish which partition you are working with.
2. Using Terminal, edit the /etc/fstab file by issuing the following command:

   `sudo nano /etc/fstab`

3.  Add the following line and be certain to change "UntitledNT" to whatever you changed it to.

```
LABEL=UntitledNT none ntfs rw,auto,nobrowse
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>O</kbd> to save the file, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> to exit.

4. Eject your drive and re-attach it.  It won't show up in Finder, so you will have to manually navigate to it.  In Terminal, just type `open /Volumes` and a finder window will open with a directory to "UntitledNT"
5. You can copy your files now (you can't write)
6. Copy your files over

### To Mount Your NTFS Partition via Terminal

Taking your output from `disktuil list` it shows that the *identifier* for your NTFS partition is `/dev/disk3s2`.

First, make a directory in your `/Volumes` folder:

```
mkdir /Volumes/ntfsdisk
```

Next, mount the drive

```
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/disk3s2 /Volumes/ntfsdisk
```

You should be able to access your data.  Copy it over, format your drive to ExFAT and copy the data back to the external drive.

Comment: How do I copy if I can't detect the drive?

Comment: Type `diskutil list` and post to your question.